# where exactly are the non ascii characters in my code i don't understand?

Tags: c++, ascii, non-ascii-characters

my english is not good sorry for my mistakes. I was solving this problem for geeks for geeks and this is the warning I got. I don't understand what's causing it, can you help me?
problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/virtual-functions/problem?isFullScreen=true

my code:

```
class Person{
    protected:
        string name;
        int age;
        int id;
        
    public:
        Person(){
            name="";
            age=0;
            id=0;
        }
        ~Person();
        virtual void getdata()=0; 
        virtual void putdata()=0;
    
};

class Professor: public Person{
    private:
        int publications;
        static int cur_id;
        
    public:
        Professor(){
            id=cur_id;
            cur_id++;
        }
        ~Professor();
        void getdata(){
       
        }

        void putdata(){

        }
    
    
};

class Student: public Person{
    private:
       int *marks;
       static int cur_id;
       
    public:
        Student(){
            id=cur_id;
            cur_id++;
            marks = new int[6];
        }
        
        void getdata(){

        }
        
        void putdata(){
      
        }
    
};
```

warning: Your submission contains non ASCII characters, we don't accept submissions with non ASCII charaters for this challenge.

Comment: Did you copy-paste this code from somewhere or typed it in the Hackerrank editor?

Comment: BTW this issue is specific to Hackerrank coding environment and probably cannot be reproduced here.

Comment: Try using [this](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~markm/ascii.html) site to check for non-ASCII characters. By the way, you can copy whatever code you have in the question and used it on Hackerrank since that code block doesn't have any ASCII.

Comment: Off-topic:  Why is the `cur_id` member in `class Professor` tagged as `static`?  The `static` key word says that all instances of `class Professor` will have the same variable, a.k.a. share the same variable.

Answer (score 1):

See this **https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/tkelioD7Fh**
Either issue in header file or using namespace std.
It will be helpful if use post entire code (URL)

Answer (score -1):

you have used '~' in ~Professor(); It is an non-ascii character.

Comment: But why would that `~` be disallowed in C++ code? You can't declare a destructor without using it! It is also, actually, a valid ASCII character (code 126).